# d3.js - Row click event?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a table and updated the data from csv using the function. The file to be read is passed as param.

```
function displayContent(file){

 d3.text(file, function(datasetText) {
   parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
   var sampleHTML = d3.select("#TableContents")
     .append("table")
     .style("border", "2px black solid")
     .attr("style", "margin-left: 20px")
     .selectAll("tr")
     .data(parsedCSV)
     .enter().append("tr")
     .selectAll("td")
     .data(function(d){return d;})
     .enter().append("td")
     .text(function(d){return d;})
     .style("font-size", "12px");
  });
}
```

I would like to have a functionality where if i click  the first column, i can show another table with details of the row selected.

For e.g, I have populated the student details in the table. Once i click any row(student id), i need to show another table based on the student selected. How do we add on click in the table row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tr` selection's [on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) method to attach a click event

For example

```
.selectAll("tr")   
 .data(parsedCSV)
 .enter().append("tr")
   .on("click", function(d) { doSomething(); })
```